# How to use multiple groups in plotly but only a defined number of legendgroups

Tags: r, r-plotly

Assuming I have a time series of multiple different cells, which I can split according to if they received a treatment or not - how can I plot all individual time series (without averaging) but group them according to the treatment in plotly?

It works perfectly with ggplot - and I know I can use ggplotly from there - but is there a full plotly way?

Here are some dummy data:

```
library("dplyr")
library("plotly")

cell <- c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10),  rep("c", 10),  rep("d", 10),  rep("e", 10), rep("f", 10))
group <- c(rep("Untreated", 10), rep("Treated", 30), rep("Unknown", 20))
time <- rep(1:10, times=6)
value <- c(runif(60))

df <- data.frame(cell, group, time, value)



# I want this in plotly:
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=value, group=cell, color=group)) +
  geom_line()


# For many "cells" this will explode the legend (my real data have hundreds of cells)
plot_ly(df, x=~time, y=~value, split=~cell, color=~group,
        type="scatter", mode="line")


# This works but it connects the last and the first timepoint
plot_ly(df, x=~time, y=~value, group=~cell, color=~group,
        type="scatter", mode="line")
```

I need this:
[image: ggplot]

But plotly gives me this (too many legendgroups for many cells):
[image: Plotly1]

Or this (it connects start and end of individual cells):
[image: Plotly2]

Is there any way plotly can do it - or do I need to use ggplotly?

Edit:

- New and extended dummy data
- New plots

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `legendgroup` and hide the duplicated trace names via `showlegend`.

Also see:
https://plotly.com/r/legend/#grouped-legend

**Edit:** After @JulianStopp modified the example data:
Here is a generalized approach to find the traces to hide in the legend. Sorry for switching to `data.table` but I'm not familiar with `dplyr`:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

cell <- c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10),  rep("c", 10),  rep("d", 10),  rep("e", 10), rep("f", 10))
group <- c(rep("Untreated", 10), rep("Treated", 30), rep("Unknown", 20))
time <- rep(1:10, times=6)
value <- c(runif(60))

DF <- data.frame(cell, group, time, value)

setDT(DF)
setorder(DF, group, cell, time)
showlegendDF <- DF[, .SD[1], by = .(group, time), .SDcols = c("cell")][, showlegend := TRUE] # find first trace for each group

DF <- showlegendDF[DF, on = c("group", "cell", "time")] # join
DF[, i := .GRP, by = .(group, cell)] # create trace indices
# set(DF, which(is.na(DF[["showlegend"]])), "showlegend", FALSE) # replace NAs with FALSE

plot_ly(DF, x=~time, y=~value, split=~cell, legendgroup = ~group, name = ~group, color = ~group,
        type="scatter", mode="line") %>% style(showlegend = FALSE, traces = unique(DF[is.na(showlegend), i]))
```

[image: result]

---

Initial answer:

```
library("dplyr")
library("plotly")

cell <- c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10),  rep("c", 10))
group <- c(rep("Untreated", 10), rep("Treated", 20))
time <- c(seq(1:10), seq(1:10), seq(1:10))
value <- c(runif(30))

df <- data.frame(cell, group, time, value)

plot_ly(df, x=~time, y=~value, split=~cell, legendgroup = ~group, name = ~group, color = ~group,
        type="scatter", mode="line") %>% style(showlegend = FALSE, traces = 2)
```

[image: result]

Comment: That works very well for the example given - but it seem not to work for my real data as "group" has multiple different groups. I assume I need to adjust traces but that also does not work for me. 
Any idea?

Comment: I actually expanded the dummy data to show the issue. If there are multiple cells in multiple groups the traces do not remove them anymore it seems - only for the first grouping.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to adapt the `traces` argument with respect to the number of traces resulting from `split`. I'm currently only on mobile. I'll check your new data tomorrow.

Comment: That did the trick - I tried something similar with dplyr which also worked at the end. Thank you a lot!